'rails new --css tailwind' Does not create either bin/dev or Procfile.dev in rails app
in short, creating a new rails app with tailwind css option in my linux terminal (e.g.):
~$ rails new depot --css tailwind --database=postqresql

does not create the necessary files to run the following command:
~/depot$ bin/dev

which when trying to run it at the mean time returns the error below:
bash: bin/dev: No such file or directory
i tried looking for this issue in coding communities, but to no avail
(please bear with me , i'm a newbie at this domain)

should it create? why should it create?

''using a CSS processor will affect how we
start our server during development. This is because things like CSS
processors and JavaScript bundlers require a build step. Rather than
requiring you to start multiple processes, Rails provides bin/dev, which is a
small script that will start everything''     (copied from "Ruby s.agile web development with rails 7" E book that I'm learning rails with.)

@AntonBogdanov
would running rails g dev:bin be of help ?


I don't see any mentioned like rails will generate this file 2) I use gem 'tailwindcss-rails' and start building with bin/rails tailwindcss:watch


@AntonBogdanov this is also a good POV thanks .

@AntonBogdanov tailwindcss-rails adds bin/dev as part of its install command https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/blob/v2.7.6/lib/install/tailwindcss.rb#L51-L53

I was working on this same problem this past week. Running Rails 7.2.1 Here are the steps I went through. Since you mentioned you are a newbie at this domain I'm making no assumptions.
Your local environment needs to have Postgres installed and the user setup beforehand.

Tailwind wasn't installed to my app even though I declared it as a an option/variable when creating the app. So I installed it again. - Install Tailwind on Rails

Set the Postgres gem to 1.5.7 in Gemfile as it was failing during installation
gem "pg", "1.5.7"


Run bundle install to install gems

Create .env in root directory and add database credentials to .env
POSTGRES_DEV_PASSWORD=yourpasswordhere


Add database env variables to config/database.yml.
development:
      <<: *default
      database: postgres_development_database
      username: your_postgres_username
      password: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_DEV_PASSWORD"] %>
      host: '127.0.0.1'


Run database migrations. bin/rails db:migrate



it was a matter of tailwind wasn't being installed after all hmm, I am so very thankful for your time, My sincere appreciation.
